# Sql server trigger : Invalid 'inserted' object name

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, trigger.io, database-trigger

I have a table that I want to test on it a trigger I try to SELECTED the line of 
the query to  see what the table contains but an error appear and In all MY sql project inserted and deleted table doesn't work for me this is what I wrote

the is the error that appear (On the Image)

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR
    on Ligne 
    for insert 
    as 
    begin
        select * from inserted
    end
```

[image]

please is there  any solution for this problem and thanks

I find that when i hover on inserted it show me this [image]

Comment: Your code works fine with me !

Comment: I just find that when i put my cursor on inserted table it show me this message  CRAETE TRIGGER is currently not supported in intelliSense Transact-sql

Comment: so update your question via adding exact error that you faced.

Comment: done i edited it :)

Comment: what is sql server version ?

Comment: Sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure intellisense is enabled in SSMS ?

Go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> IntelliSense

[image]

Then - if it is enabled - sometimes it helps to refresh the local cache:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing an `i` at the back of the keyword, inserted?

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR
    on Ligne 
    for insert 
    as 
    begin
        select * from inserted i
    end
```

Comment: when i put my cursor on inserted table it show me this message CRAETE TRIGGER is currently not supported in intelliSense Transact-sql

Comment: @mohammedaamoum are you able to show some screenshots of the error?

Comment: when i hover on inserted then it show me the message i  cant screen hovering doesnt allow me but i will try to describe when the message show up

Comment: back above i have edited my question and add screenshoot and thanks for support

Comment: @mohammedaamoum have you ensure that your IntelliSense is enabled?

Comment: I just found that my intellisense was disabled thanks for help

Comment: @mohammedaamoum you're most welcome! glad you are able to solve it.